# Problems using some functions in a data frame

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R and I'm having some trouble working with a dataset. I have an Arduino device that collects local humidity and temperature and stores it in a 'txt' file with a timestamp for the measurements (So I have date, time, humidity and temperature in °C).

I can open the file in RStudio but can't perform operations with it. For example, I need to take the mean from temperature and humidity readings and plot a graph but it just doesn't work. Every time I use `mean()` it returns NA as a result. There is nothing special inside the file, I kept it as simple as it could be. What am I doing wrong?

I'll probably have problems with the date and hour formats too, so any insights on the will be helpfull.

Thanks!

**Additional info**
I'm using the following code to read the file and work with the dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
df <- read.table('logger.TXT', header = TRUE, sep = ';', dec = '.')
mt <- mean(df$temp) ## calculates the mean for temperature
my <- mean(df$hum) ## calculates the mean for humidity
```

OBS: the code works if I use summarise:

```
df %>%
summarise(mean_t, mean(temp, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**dataset info**
- Measurements are stored in a 'txt' file. 
- The first line is the header (day;hour;hum;temp)
- Date format is dd/mm/yyyy
- Hour format is hh:mm:ss (24h hour format)
- Decimal places for hum and temp are divided with '.'
- Here is the header for the data frame:

```
        day     hour  hum temp
1 19/3/2020 13:39:34 53.0 31.8
2 19/3/2020 13:54:34 53.1 31.7
3 19/3/2020  14:9:33 53.5 30.9
4 19/3/2020 14:24:33 54.1 31.2
5 19/3/2020 14:39:33 53.8 31.3
6 19/3/2020 14:54:33 53.5 31.4
```

- Failed readings are stored as blank spaces so R interprets it as NAs

Comment: Use `na.rm = TRUE` in `mean` i.e `mt <- mean(df$temp, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Hint: `dplyr`, `ggplot2` and `readr` are part of `tidyverse`

Comment: Thanks, Ronak and Martin for the responses. Just to be clear, if I use `tidyverse` I don't have to load the other libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting Ronak Shah's answer because it may be useful for other people.

> Use `na.rm = TRUE in mean i.e mt <- mean(df$temp, na.rm = TRUE)`

Thanks!